# How to find specific data in database

Tags: sql, database

Question: Find the names of all employees in the database who earn more than every employee of 'Small Bank Corporation'. Assume that all people work for at most one company.

[image]

I tried this SQL command

```
SELECT employee-name, salary
FROM works
WHERE salary>salary.works(SELECT company-name="Small Bank Corporation");
```

Of course the command doesn't work so I need help on this question, help is much appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query was almost correct:

```
SELECT
    [employee-name]
    ,[salary]
FROM works
WHERE salary > (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM works WHERE [company-name] = 'Small Bank Corporation')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  employee-name
FROM works
WHERE salary > (SELECT
  MAX(salary)
FROM works
WHERE company-name = 'Small Bank Corporation');
```

Comment: May be change `'Small Bank Corporation'` by `?`

Comment: This is the answer to the question you asked @extails19

Comment: I guess is my queries bugged, i open a new one to run the code and everything works fine.
Thanks for the help!